Enthalpy in isochoric process
Let's consider a constant volume heating process of a gas. The heat $Q$ is added to the system and raises the temperature and pressure of the gas.
There is no work done by the gas since volume is kept constant:
$$W=0$$
By first law, $Q=\text{change in internal energy}(\Delta U+W)$.
Since there is no work, internal energy change = heat input:
$$\Delta U = Q$$
But what is the enthalpy change?
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (PV)$$
$\Delta (PV) \gt 0$ since the pressure is increased. Or we can just look at these equations: $\Delta U=C_v \Delta T$, $\Delta H=C_p \Delta T$, so that we know $\Delta H \gt \Delta U$.
In this case, since all heat input $Q$ becomes increase in internal energy, it becomes kind of like change in enthalpy is greater than the input heat $Q$.
I can't understand it. Is enthalpy not a term of energy?

Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions

It seems you imply the work sign convention "work done by the system"  $\Delta U = Q - W$. Note that in science and chemistry there is preferred the convention "work done to/on the system"  $\Delta U = Q + W$. // The former convention is preferred in engineering and historically in physics, but physics significantly migrates lately to the latter one. // To avoid confusion, it is always a good habit to explicitly mention which convetion is used.

U  + x [J] or  U * x[1] are still terms of energy. They can but need not have direct physical interpretation.

Enthalpy is a convenient quantity which often arises in many practical situations, but it is not a fundamental energy entity like internal energy.  For isochoric heating, $\Delta H=\Delta U+V\Delta P>\Delta U$.  No big deal.

Thank you for the answer Mr. But in steady flow equation, enthalpy is kind of treated as a form of energy. That is what making me so confused.

That’s because in the derivation of the steady flow equation part of the work to push material into went out of the system is lumped in with the internal energy of the flowing stream to give the term Involving enthalpy.  This is an example of what I was trying to say.
